# Linux WindowMaker/Docky padding issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nautilus, docky

I've recently made the switch to a custom Ubuntu installation (replacing Unity with WindowMaker). Everything works fine, except I have issues handling the windows while Docky + compositing (I already tried xcompmgr, cairo-compmgr and unagi) is enabled.

Basically, I can't move any window past the 2/3 of the screen or I'll immediately lose control (the WindowMaker docklet application icon confirms this by switching from the "Nautilus/Desktop" icon to the "Docky" application icon) and can't drag those windows in any direction anymore.

It's as if there was a physical frame around the Docky dock that stretches all the way inwards, albeit a transparent one. Is there any way to remedy this?

PS: Sometimes, I also can't click on any of the Docky icons because the focus will still be with Nautilus. Disabling Nautilus will remedy this, but not the first situation (even without Nautilus, I can't move simple xTerm windows past the 2/3 of the screen. It does work with compositing turned off, though.